# Print all the data from a SQLite table into a single string

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, sqlite

I want users to be able to see all their quizzes created on my website. These lists are saved in a SQLite database with a column "quiz name" and a column "username". 
It should work as follows:

1. the user types a username in the textbox

2. the script prints all quiz names created by the user typed in the textbox. (like all quizes created by 'user1'

3. the names are printed in a list.

**EXAMPLE**

1. the user types my username in the textbox:
[image: user textbox]

 2. the script scans the database in the "gebruiker" column for "eliasgroot".
 **I don't want the quiz name from the quiz created by "user1"**[image]

3. the names from the quizzes are printed in a list. So in this example it would look like:

> Quizzes created by eliasgroot:
>   
> 1. Quiz english
>   
> 2. Quiz French

**THE SOLUTION**
I'm using a script that works from getting one quiz name into a string. But it does not print all data from the column. So it only prints:

> Quizzes created by eliasgroot:
>   
> Quiz english

It prints this name into a single string called "vertaling" but when I searched online I found many articles about using lists. Not sure how this works though.
Is there a way to get it working like in the example? 

PS and beside that, is there a way to make the input in the textbox case insensitive? e.g. when a user types EliasGroot instead of eliasgroot he gets the same results?

Thanks in advance, Elias
**MY CODE:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Scripts_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string connectionString =
         @"Data Source=C:/Users/elias/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/WebSites/WebSite7/App_Data/overhoren.db";

        using (var conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

               //defines the "woord" string which contains the username the 
               //user typed in
            string woord = TextBox1.Text;

              //defines the "geenvertaling" string which is displayed if no 
              //quizzes are found in the database.
            string geenvertaling = "er is geen vertaling gevonden";


            using (var command = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(conn))
            {
                command.Connection = conn;

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@woord", woord);

                //searches the database for quizzes (vertaling) for the 
                //username that is equal to @woord (typed in the textbox by 
                //user.
                command.CommandText =
                   @"SELECT[vertaling], [woord] FROM[tbWoorden] WHERE[gebruiker] = @woord";


                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    string vertaling = "";
                    if (reader.Read())
                        vertaling = $"{reader["vertaling"]}";

                //checks weither or not there are found quizzes according to 
                //the username typed in and then prints an error message or 
                //the quizzes name.
                    if (vertaling == "")
                    {
                        lblTest.Text = geenvertaling;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblTest.Text = vertaling;
                    }


                }


            }
            }
    }



    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void grdMijnLijsten_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Seems like repeaters are the perfect solution. I followed [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx) and changed the path and connection string in the web.config. Still it gives the error: network path not found. 
I think it's a SQL/SQLite problem but I'm not familiar with it and don't know what I'm doing wrong. My code is as follows:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
          DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
          <HeaderTemplate>
              <table>
              <tr>
                 <th>Name</th>
                 <th>Description</th>
              </tr>
          </HeaderTemplate>

          <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" 
                    text='<%# Eval("vertaling") %>' />
              </td>
              <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" 
                      text='<%# Eval("woord") %>' />
              </td>
          </tr>
          </ItemTemplate>

          <AlternatingItemTemplate>
          <tr>
              <td >
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label3" 
                    text='<%# Eval("vertaling") %>' />
              </td>
              <td >
                 <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label4" 
                     text='<%# Eval("woord") %>' />
              </td>
          </tr>
          </AlternatingItemTemplate>

          <FooterTemplate>
              </table>
          </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>

      <asp:SqlDataSource 
          ConnectionString=
              "<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>"
          ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
          SelectCommand="SELECT [woord], [vertaling] FROM [tbWoorden]">
      </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And this is my web.config code snippet:

```
<connectionStrings>   
 <add
      name="NorthwindConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=C:/Users/elias/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/WebSites/WebSite7/App_Data/overhoren.db" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: So basically, you want to render a list? if so you could take a look at ASP.NET Repeaters

Comment: @kblok thank you! Did not even know repeaters existed. I used ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx) this article  , which was really helpfull. One question: I replaced the database file path in the web.config but it seems not to work with SQLite. What should I change? (i'll put my new code in the updated question)

[1]:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but in the Code i See that You are reading olny one row from Resultset that is returned by the reader Object.

You should try something like below to read all rows in a loop:

```
StringBuilder listSB = new StringBuilder();
int lineNumber = 0;
while(reader.Read()) 
{
    lineNumber++; 
    string vertaling = "";
    if (reader.Read()) 
    {
        vertaling = $"{reader["vertaling"]}";
    }

    if (!vertaling.Equals(""))
    {
        listSB.Append(listSB.Length > 0 ? "\n": "").Append(lineNumber).Append(". ").Append(vertaling);
    }
}

if (listSB.Length > 0)
{
    lblTest.Text = listSB.ToString();
}
else 
{
    lblTest.Text = geenvertaling;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I tested the code and it gave the "geenvertaling" string (the error message) even if it shouldn't. What do I have to change?

Comment: Hello,You must change (remove) the Else part of the if else Statement. See below: <code>
    if (listSB.Length > 0)
    {
        lblTest.Text = listSB.ToString();
    }
    else 
    {
        lblTest.Text = geenvertaling;
    }
</code>

Comment: You can do something like below:

    // if resultset has data
    if (listSB.Length > 0)
    {
        lblTest.Text = listSB.ToString();
    }
    // if no data found
    if (lineNumber == 0) 
    {
        lblTest.Text = geenvertaling;
    }

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a stupid mistake. Your first code is just working fine and I really wanna thank you for it! It helps a lot!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help You